# How do I make Chrome forget a "no" to geolocation on a site?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

I'm not sure where the problem lies, as for the page I am developing I can't remember giving a "no" to geospatial information, but through whatever means I have a Chrome installation that is acting on a refusal to share geospatial information.

How can I clear Chrome's memory that I at some point rejected permission to geospatial information? Will some form of "clear browser data" give me a fresh slate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.
- In the dialog that appears, scroll down to the "Location" section.
- Click Manage exceptions.

Source: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065

Also be sure to check all other Privacy and Content settings for default behavior.

Comment: And your response didn't just provide the option of clearing a setting; it also let me see that I had provided geolocation to the site in question.

Comment: For information, when you use Chrome for Android, you have to open Chrome's menu, tap "Settings", "Content settings", "Web sites settings", then search for the website in the list and tap to open it, then finally check or uncheck "Access to my position". If you want Chrome to forget a "no", you have to check and uncheck it, which will cause Chrome to remove the saved decision (the site doesn't appear in the list anymore).

Comment: TLDR: Paste chrome://settings/content/location in address bar, then follow last step in above list

Answer (score 16):

You can probably just change your setting by clicking the site icon:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If previous answers don't solve your problem, is possible you were using Chrome 50+ on a HTTP not secure domain. This article explains why Chrome fails while detecting geolocation and how to detect when this is happening: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(success) { /* Do some magic. */ },
  function(failure) {
    if(failure.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
      // Chrome 50+, no HTTP domain.
    }
  };
});
```